# Website blank while running nginx and wordpress through docker

Tags: linux, database, wordpress, docker, nginx

I've been following a tutorial to setup a website on a raspberry pi using docker.

I'm running the following in my yaml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  db: 
    build: ./db
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: *Blocking out my password*
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: *Blocking out my password*
    networks:
      website_network:
        aliases: 
          - wordpress
  
  wordpress:
    build: .
    container_name: wordpress
    ports:
      - "80"
    networks:
      website_network:
        aliases: 
          - wordpress
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: *Blocking out my password*
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80"
    networks:
      website_network:
        aliases:
          - nginx-proxy
      
networks:
  website_network: 
    name: website_network

volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
    name: db_data
```

I have some additional files which are taking the wildcard encyption files, unzipping them and running them inside the nginx container. My problem is that when I run all the containers, the website "appears" but its basically a blank screen. my code doesn't have any typos from what I can tell, so I'm a bit stuck. I think that my cointainers aren't really talking to each other anymore. The encrpyting works since the website is accessible through https:

I don't know if I can be help, but I've been stuck for about a week now and I'm at a loss. I might just find another tutorial.

Ive been trying to recheck the code, uninstalling images and reinstalling them using docker-compose prune or docker container --remove-orphans, etc. I've tried taking it down and putting it back up, building the containers first but nothing seems to help. I'm really stuck. My guess is it's something stupid and I'm just missing it.

Comment: maybe check logs? `docker logs <container_name>`

Comment: Great suggestion. On my nginx I'm seeing different version of the following when I try to access the website:
[error] 20#20: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 


DNS is through cloudflare.